# How I can get refresh token of fitBit

Tags: fitbit

I need to implement FitBit in my application. All functionality is working fine. I am able to solve two problems. One is how I can get refresh token and another is how I can get steps between two dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this?

```
GET /1/user/[user-id]/[resource-path]/date/[base-date]/[end-date].json
```

seems to be exactly what you are looking for... read more here https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/activity/

Comment: Thanks Jesus. Can you please tell me how I can get refresh token?

Comment: it is also on the API Docs. https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/#refreshing-tokens

Basically when the token expires you will get an http error 401 and then handle it accordingly